# How to write a video encoder with ffmpeg that explicitly controls the position of keyframes?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

I want to write an encoder with ffmpeg which can put iFrames (keyframes) at positions I want. Where can I found tutorials or reference material for it?

P.S
 Is it possible to do this with mencoder or any opensource encoder. I want to encode H263 file. I am writing under & for linux.

Comment: I can write in C, c++ but tutorial or reference can be in any language. I just want to know/understand ffmpeg api.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to look at the libavcodec documentation - specifically, at avcodec_encode_video(). I found that the best available documentation is in the ffmpeg header files and the API sample source code that's provided with the ffmpeg source. Specifically, look at libavcodec/api-example.c or even ffmpeg.c.

To force an I frame, you'll need to set the pict_type member of the picture you're encoding to 1: 1 is an I frame, 2 is a P frame, and I don't remember what's the code for a B frame off the top of my head... Also, the key_frame member needs to be set to 1.

Some introductory material is available [here](http://web.me.com/dhoerl/Home/Tech_Blog/Entries/2009/1/22_Revised_avcodec_sample.c.html) and [here](http://www.cryptosystem.org/archives/2006/03/libavcodec-libavformat-sample-code/), but I don't really know how good it is.

You'll need to be careful how you allocate the frame objects that the API calls require. api-example.c is your best bet as far as that goes, in my opinion. Look for the function video_encode_example() - it's concise and illustrates all the important things you need to worry about - pay special attention to the second call to avcodec_encode_video() that passes a NULL picture argument - it's required to get the last frames of video since MPEG video is encoded out of sequence and you may end up with a delay of a few frames.

Comment: Btw, the values for the `pict_type` member of the picture are `AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I`, `AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P`, `AV_PICTURE_TYPE_B`, and so on...

Answer (score 4):

An up-to-date version of api-example.c can be found at http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html

It does the entire video encoding in a single and relatively short function. So this is probably a good place to start. Compile and run it. And then start modifying it until it does what you want.

It also has audio encoding and audio & video decoding examples.

Comment: It is better to look for the official documentation for up-to-date version: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html

Answer (score 3):

[GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) has [decent documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/), has bindings for a [number of languages](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/) (although the native API is C), and supports any video format you can find plugins for, including H.263 via [gstreamer-ffmpeg](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-ffmpeg.html).

Answer (score 1):

you will need libavcodec library, For the first step I think you can learn about its use in ffplay.c file inside ffmpeg source code. It would tell you a lot. You can check my project also about video at rtstegvideo.sourceforge.net.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're Java programmer then use Xuggler.

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal runnable example on FFmpeg 2.7**

Based on [Ori Pessach's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328286/895245) answer, below is a minimal example that generates frames of form.

- I
- P
- B
- P
- ...

The key parts of the code that control frame type are:

```
c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
/* Minimal distance of I-frames. This is the maximum value allowed,
or else we get a warning at runtime. */
c->keyint_min = 600;
/* Or else it defaults to 0 b-frames are not allowed. */
c->max_b_frames = 1;
```

and:

```
frame->key_frame = 0;
switch (frame->pts % 4) {
    case 0:
        frame->key_frame = 1;
        frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
    break;
    case 1:
    case 3:
        frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P;
    break;
    case 2:
        frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_B;
    break;
}
```

We can then verify the frame type with:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v \
    -show_frames \
    -show_entries frame=pict_type \
    -of csv \
    tmp.h264
```

as mentioned at: https://superuser.com/questions/885452/extracting-the-index-of-key-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg

Some rules were enforced by FFmpeg even if I try to overcome them:

- the first frame is an I-frame
- cannot place a B0frame before an I-frame (TODO why?)

[Preview of generated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1U8.jpg).

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

static AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPacket pkt;
static FILE *file;
struct SwsContext *sws_context = NULL;

/*
Convert RGB24 array to YUV. Save directly to the `frame`,
modifying its `data` and `linesize` fields
*/
static void ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(uint8_t *rgb) {
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 3 * c->width };
    sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context,
            c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            0, 0, 0, 0);
    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb, in_linesize, 0,
            c->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}

/*
Generate 2 different images with four colored rectangles, each 25 frames long:

Image 1:

    black | red
    ------+-----
    green | blue

Image 2:

    yellow | red
    -------+-----
    green  | white
*/
uint8_t* generate_rgb(int width, int height, int pts, uint8_t *rgb) {
    int x, y, cur;
    rgb = realloc(rgb, 3 * sizeof(uint8_t) * height * width);
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            cur = 3 * (y * width + x);
            rgb[cur + 0] = 0;
            rgb[cur + 1] = 0;
            rgb[cur + 2] = 0;
            if ((frame->pts / 25) % 2 == 0) {
                if (y < height / 2) {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        /* Black. */
                    } else {
                        rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                    } else {
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (y < height / 2) {
                    rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                    } else {
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    } else {
                        rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rgb;
}

/* Allocate resources and write header data to the output file. */
void ffmpeg_encoder_start(const char *filename, int codec_id, int fps, int width, int height) {
    AVCodec *codec;
    int ret;
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->width = width;
    c->height = height;
    c->time_base.num = 1;
    c->time_base.den = fps;
    /* I, P, B frame placement parameters. */
    c->gop_size = 600;
    c->max_b_frames = 1;
    c->keyint_min = 600;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/*
Write trailing data to the output file
and free resources allocated by ffmpeg_encoder_start.
*/
void ffmpeg_encoder_finish(void) {
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
    int got_output, ret;
    do {
        fflush(stdout);
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (got_output) {
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
    } while (got_output);
    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), file);
    fclose(file);
    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
}

/*
Encode one frame from an RGB24 input and save it to the output file.
Must be called after ffmpeg_encoder_start, and ffmpeg_encoder_finish
must be called after the last call to this function.
*/
void ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(uint8_t *rgb) {
    int ret, got_output;
    ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(rgb);
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;
    switch (frame->pts % 4) {
        case 0:
            frame->key_frame = 1;
            frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
        break;
        case 1:
        case 3:
            frame->key_frame = 0;
            frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P;
        break;
        case 2:
            frame->key_frame = 0;
            frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_B;
        break;
    }
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (got_output) {
        fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
}

/* Represents the main loop of an application which generates one frame per loop. */
static void encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id) {
    int pts;
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;
    uint8_t *rgb = NULL;
    ffmpeg_encoder_start(filename, codec_id, 25, width, height);
    for (pts = 0; pts < 100; pts++) {
        frame->pts = pts;
        rgb = generate_rgb(width, height, pts, rgb);
        ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(rgb);
    }
    ffmpeg_encoder_finish();
}

int main(void) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    encode_example("tmp.h264", AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    encode_example("tmp.mpg", AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    /* TODO: is this encoded correctly? Possible to view it without container? */
    /*encode_example("tmp.vp8", AV_CODEC_ID_VP8);*/
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/19044698f91fefa9cb75328c44f7a487d336b541/ffmpeg/encode.c).

**Do you *really* want to do this?**

In most cases, you are better off just controlling the global parameters of `AVCodecContext`.

FFmpeg does smart things like using a keyframe if the new frame is completely different from the previous one, and not much would be gained from differential encoding.

For example, if we set just:

```
c->keyint_min = 600;
```

then we get exactly 4 key-frames on the above example, which is logical since there are 4 abrupt frame changes on the generated video.