# Has any one compiled lib x264 using CLI backend for gcc compiler?

Tags: c#, .net, c, x264

Has any one compiled lib x264 using [CLI backend for gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cli.html) compiler? (Compiled x264 into .net dll)

Comment: I don't find this very likely. Out of curiosity, why can't you p/invoke the library - is it just too large to wrap. (how many methods/structs in particular would you need to wrap, because if it's a reasonable amount I'll help you do it.)

Comment: @Mark H: all I want is minimum for encoding of frames (frame by frame)... So at least ones that are listed in this sample 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940671/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-h264-using-x264-api-c-c/2940700#2940700 


x264_param_t,
X264_RC_CRF,
x264_t*,
picture_t,
x264_nal_t*,


x264_param_default_preset();
x264_param_apply_profile();
x264_encoder_open();
x264_picture_alloc();
x264_encoder_encode();

Comment: ok, `x264_param_t` is huge, but I'll give it a shot anyway. No promises.

Comment: mail me or post here - if you'd do it - it'd be grate! superior0 at ya dot ru

Comment: If you already have a built x264.dll you could upload, it'd make alot easier for me to test btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using C99 features?  If not, Visual C++ with the `/clr:pure` option should do the trick.  You will need a little bit of C++/CLI mixed in to define your entrypoints that other .NET projects can call, but those can be in completely separate files (you can share entire C-only source files with native projects).

EDIT: Basic guide to making this work:

- In Visual Studio, create a C++/CLI Class Library project
- Add all your C source files to the project
- In Project Configuration, set the include path so your headers are found
- In Project Configuration, also set "Use of Common Language Runtime" to `/clr:pure`
- In the .cpp file created by the new project wizard, add `#include` directive for the header files which prototype the functions you want to use.
- In the `ref class` created by the new project wizard (in the aforementioned .cpp file), add some functions (maybe static functions) which call your C library functions.
- Compile, add this .DLL as a reference of your C# project, and enjoy

As a hint, instead of creating a forwarding function in the `ref class` for every function in the library, you may want to make functions that do useful work (for the particular definition of useful for your particular project) by calling a bunch of library functions.

You'll probably want to get comfortable with the `marshal_as` template which is good for converting .NET `System::String` into C strings and back again.

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample for such thing - looks grate for me

Comment: For this, a snippet of example code wouldn't be very helpful.  But I've edited my answer to describe the procedure.