# Where ffmpeg flags like CODEC_FLAG2_BPYRAMID are located?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, libavcodec, libx264

I'm developing on using VS2010 with ffmpeg and tried the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553003/encoding-h-264-with-libavcodec-x264). But VS says that it cannot find

1. `CODEC_FLAG2_BPYRAMID+CODEC_FLAG2_MIXED_REFS+CODEC_FLAG2_WPRED+CODEC_FLAG2_8X8DCT+CODEC_FLAG2_FASTPSKIP;  // flags2=+bpyramid+mixed_refs+wpred+dct8x8+fastpskip`
2. `X264_PART_I8X8+X264_PART_I4X4+X264_PART_P8X8+X264_PART_B8X8`
3. `avCodecContext.crf`

Where are they located?

Comment: They are in `libavcodec\avcodec.h` and other FFmpeg files you are supposed to include to access the constants and other declarations.

Comment: I downloaded the source from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. I searched in WHOLE source directory and didn't find any CODEC_FLAG2_BPYRAMID. Even not in`libavcodec\avcodec.h`. What I'm missing?

Comment: This particular flag is [deprecated](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/doxygen/trunk/group__deprecated__flags.html). You are supposed to used named option `b-pyramid` instead.

Comment: @RomanR. the reason I ask is because I has fps issues when transcoding from avi to h264/mp4 (http://libav-users.943685.n4.nabble.com/Libav-user-fps-porblem-when-saving-video-in-mp4-container-td4656102.html) I think my params in code are wrong, so I checked which params the ffmpeg application itself uses in order to convert from avi to mp4 and I thought to map them to params in **code**, but I couldn't map many of them. I'll be glad for some help. If I need to open different post I'll do it.

Comment: I saw your question on FFmpeg mailing list, maybe someone there will respond to you with a code snippet or anything better than my reference to documentation and source code. My understanding is that you need to use named options, and the code you found was for older version of `libav*`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The problem that I've posted my issue in many forums and still no one gave me solution:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RomanR said, some flags and params were deprecated. But, we can still set them using `av_opt_set` function. For example, to set `crf=23` we use `av_opt_set(outStream->codec->priv_data, "crf", "23", 0);`