# How to generate a word frequency histogram, where bars are ordered according to their height

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram, ranking

I have a long list of words, and I want to generate a histogram of the frequency of each word in my list. I was able to do that in the code below:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

word_list = ['A','A','B','B','A','C','C','C','C']

counts = Counter(merged)

labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))

plt.bar(indexes, values)
plt.show()
```

It doesn't, however, display the bins by rank (i.e. by frequency, so highest frequency is first bin on the left and so on), even though when I print `counts` it orders them for me `Counter({'C': 4, 'A': 3, 'B': 2})`. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by sorting your data first and then pass the ordered arrays to `bar`; below I use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for that. The plot then looks as follows (I also added the labels to the bar):

[image]

Here is the code that produces the plot with a few inline comments:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

word_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']

counts = Counter(word_list)

labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

# sort your values in descending order
indSort = np.argsort(values)[::-1]

# rearrange your data
labels = np.array(labels)[indSort]
values = np.array(values)[indSort]

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))

bar_width = 0.35

plt.bar(indexes, values)

# add labels
plt.xticks(indexes + bar_width, labels)
plt.show()
```

In case you want to plot only the first `n` entries, you can replace the line

```
counts = Counter(word_list)
```

by

```
counts = dict(Counter(word_list).most_common(n))
```

In the case above, `counts` would then be

```
{'A': 3, 'C': 4}
```

for `n = 2`.

If you like to remove the frame of the plot and label the bars directly, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42741202/1534017).

Comment: I have more than 4000 words to count, so how to generate word frequency histogram of only top 20 words?

Comment: @AAKM: You can use `counts.most_common(20)` i.e. `counts = Counter(word_list).most_common(20)`.

Comment: AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-704ddcc6ce26> in <module>()
      5 counts = Counter(df['Text']).most_common(10)
      6 
----> 7 labels, values = zip(*counts.items())
      8 
      9 # sort your values in descending order

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @AAKM: True, `most_common` returns a list, not a dictionary, I updated the post. So, `dict(Counter(word_list).most_common(20))` should work for you now.