# Is it possible to remove the border?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I have this code using matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1],[1])
ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both', length=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I would like to have this :

[image]

I mean I just want to remove the black border.

It it possible ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908576/how-to-remove-frame-from-matplotlib-pyplot-figure-vs-matplotlib-figure-frame

Answer (score 1):

use `ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)` to control visibility of boarders

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1],[1])
ax.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both', length=0)

ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

output

[image]