# Renderer problems using Matplotlib from within a script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've narrowed down to this call:

```
fig.canvas.tostring_argb() #fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
```

this function raises an `AttributeError` when I run the code as a python script.
`AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasGTKAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'`

However, this code works properly if run in the `ipython --pylab` command line.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, the Agg renderer should work OK.

The context is that I'm trying to make a movie from figures, without saving the frames
to disk; as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092927/generating-movie-from-python-without-saving-individual-frames-to-files).  I'm using the approach that streams the pixel arrays 
to `ffmpeg` (running as a separate  process) to do this, I need the `argb` array of values from the frame.

Is there some configuration setting I can make to get matplotlib to work correctly from within a script?

*Edit* 
Tried `use('Agg')` as per a comment; still fails;  this is a minimal working example.

```
[dave@dave tools]$ python -c "import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg'); import matplotlib.pyplot; fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure(); fig.canvas.tostring_argb()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 416, in tostring_argb
    return self.renderer.tostring_argb()
AttributeError: FigureCanvasAgg instance has no attribute 'renderer'
```

Comment: put `matplotlib.use('Agg')` at the top of your script.  The issue is that you are trying to use a gui backend with out properly setting it up.  It would be better if you could generate a 10 line script which demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up installing and using the `WXAgg` backend; the `Agg`,and default `GTKAgg`, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 36):

I suspect that you have missed out the call to:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

before

```
fig.canvas.tostring_argb()
```

as

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot
fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
fig.canvas.tostring_argb()
```

fails for me, but

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot
fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.tostring_argb()
```

works.