# How to convert Matplotlib figure to PIL Image object (without saving image)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

As the title states, I am trying to convert a `fig` to a `PIL.Image`. I am currently able to do so by first saving the `fig` to disk and then opening that file using `Image.open()` but the process is taking longer than expected and I am hoping that by skipping the saving locally step it will be a bit faster.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# build fig
figsize, dpi = self._calc_fig_size_res(img_height)
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=figsize)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(torch.from_numpy(S).flip(0), cmap = cmap)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right = 1, bottom = 0, top = 1)
ax.axis('tight'); ax.axis('off')

# export
fig.savefig(export_path, dpi = dpi)

# open image as PIL object
img = Image.open(export_path)
```

I have tried doing this after I build the fig (it would be right before the export stage):

```
pil_img = Image.frombytes('RGB', canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
```

But it's not showing the entire image. It looks like it's a crop of the top left corner, but it could just be a weird representation of the data -- I'm working with spectrograms so the images are fairly abstract.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

EDIT # 2

```
PIL.Image.frombytes('RGB', 
fig.canvas.get_width_height(),fig.canvas.tostring_rgb())
```

takes around 2ms compared to the 35/40ms of the below.

This is the fastest way I can find so far.

---

I've been looking at this also today.

In the matplotlib docs the savefig function had this.

> pil_kwargsdict, optional Additional keyword arguments that are passed
> to PIL.Image.save when saving the figure. Only applicable for formats
> that are saved using Pillow, i.e. JPEG, TIFF, and (if the keyword is
> set to a non-None value) PNG.

This must mean it's already a pil image before saving but I can't see it.

You could follow this

[Matplotlib: save plot to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821518/matplotlib-save-plot-to-numpy-array)

To get it into a numpy array and then do

`PIL.Image.fromarray(array)`

You might need to reverse the channels from BGR TO RGB with array `[:, :, ::-1]`

EDIT:

I've tested each way come up with so far.

```
import io
    
def save_plot_and_get():
    fig.savefig("test.jpg")
    img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    return PIL.Image.fromarray(img)
    
def buffer_plot_and_get():
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    return PIL.Image.open(buf)
    
def from_canvas():
    lst = list(fig.canvas.get_width_height())
    lst.append(3)
    return PIL.Image.fromarray(np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape(lst))
```

Results

```
%timeit save_plot_and_get()
```

35.5 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit save_plot_and_get()
```

35.5 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit buffer_plot_and_get()
```

40.4 ms ± 152 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: Note that this can be matplotlib backend-dependent - some backends (such as QTAgg) require the canvas to be drawn via fig.canvas.draw() to initialize the renderer before using tostring_rgb(). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407794/10342097

Comment: Unfortunately, this puts a large while border around my image.

Comment: fig.canvas.tostring_rgb() is deprecated. Use fig.canvas.buffer_rgba() instead, being sure to change "RGB" to "RGBa". The RGBa image can be converted to RGB with `img.convert("RGB")`. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.tostring_rgb

Answer (score 22):

I use the following function:

```py
def fig2img(fig):
    """Convert a Matplotlib figure to a PIL Image and return it"""
    import io
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    img = Image.open(buf)
    return img
```

Example usage:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

x = np.arange(-3,3)
plt.plot(x)
fig = plt.gcf()

img = fig2img(fig)

img.show()
```

Comment: This worked and was extremely efficient, but why does the "img.show()" function open the images in preview instead of within the jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3):

I flagged it as a duplicate and then closed it because I used the wrong link.

Anyway the answer may be here:

[how to save a pylab figure into in-memory file which can be read into PIL image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598673/how-to-save-a-pylab-figure-into-in-memory-file-which-can-be-read-into-pil-image/8598881)

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely an improvement, as it is an `Image` object and it's showing the right image and I'm not saving it to disk. However, for some reason the resolution of the image is much lower than if I were to save it to disk and then reload it, a problem that I also had when following this process: http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/tutorials/convert_a_matplotlib_figure | I'll edit my post with examples

Comment: I take that back -- I just forgot to include the `dpi` argument, which makes sense why the resolution was lower. So thank you!! I wouldn't mark it as a duplicate because the problem is slightly different but if you feel it is then you can flag. Either way, that solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this did not lead to any speed increases, but I'll still post my specific solution below in case anyone has a similar issue:

```
# build fig
figsize, dpi = self._calc_fig_size_res(img_height)
fig = plt.Figure(figsize = figsize)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(torch.from_numpy(S).flip(0), cmap = camp)
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right = 1, bottom = 0, top = 1)
ax.axis('tight'); ax.axis('off')

# convert to PIL Image object
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi = dpi)
buf.seek(0)
pil_img = deepcopy(Image.open(buf))
buf.close()
```

Comment: where is "deepcopy"?