# Saving a matplotlib figure in BMP format

Tags: python

I am using these libraries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im
```

My code is as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=250) # 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
pos1 =ax1.imshow(amplitud_DCO08,cmap='gray')
ax1.title.set_text('Amplitud del DCO')
fig.savefig('AmplitudDCO_escalado08',dpi=250, format='bmp')
```

I am trying to save the image using the following line of code:

```
fig.savefig('AmplitudDCO_escalado08',dpi=250, format='bmp')
```

However this shows me the error:

```
Format 'bmp' is not supported(supported formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff).
```

I need an image in `.bmp` format, because I need it quantized at 8 bits. How can I solve this problem? Or there is another way to save an imagen in `.bmp` format?

Comment: Both BMP and PNG can save to 8 bits with a palette, but they can save 24 bits too so it won't happen automatically.  You need to apply a palette as a separate step.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Matplotlib does not support saving in BMP format. You'll have to convert the figure into a Pillow image first, and then save that. To do this, you can use `PIL.Image.frombytes()` as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61756899/3889449).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image as im

fig = plt.figure(dpi=250) # 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
pos1 =ax1.imshow(amplitud_DCO08,cmap='gray')
ax1.title.set_text('Amplitud del DCO')

image = im.frombytes('RGB', fig.canvas.get_width_height(), fig.canvas.tostring_rgb())
image.save('AmplitudDCO_escalado08.bmp')
```

Answer (score 1):

If **bmp** is not supported as a save format. Then I guess there is no other way that let you save it as **bmp** with plt directly. If so, what we can do is to save it as **.PNG** first and then convert it to bmp. We can use `PIL` to do this. And you have PIL in your code so.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=250) # 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
pos1 =ax1.imshow(amplitud_DCO08,cmap='gray')
ax1.title.set_text('Amplitud del DCO')
fig.savefig('AmplitudDCO_escalado08.PNG',dpi=250))
im.open("AmplitudDCO_escalado08.PNG").save("AmplitudDCO_escalado08.bmp")
```