# Which backend should I use for animations with matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, backend

I have an animation job that takes a long time and a lot of memory. I want to submit it to a [TORQUE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORQUE_Resource_Manager) queue, but I can't use X on those machines. Since "default" matplotlib requires X, I need to import it like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("AGG")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

What's passed to the `use()` method is called a backend. The documentation on backends can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html).

Which backend should I use if I'm using `matplotlib.animate()` and want to save the animation as an mp4 or theora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saving of movies is handled by the `writer` objects in the `animation` module and have nothing to do with the backend you set using `use`.  If you need to run your script without X then setting `use('Agg')` is the correct thing to do.

See [Generating movie from python without saving individual frames to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092927/generating-movie-from-python-without-saving-individual-frames-to-files/13983801#13983801) and the `animation.writer` module attribute (which is a registry of the writers matplotlib found on your system).