# Speedup matplotlib animation to video file

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

On Raspbian (Raspberry Pi 2), the following minimal example stripped from my script correctly produces an mp4 file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def anim_lift(x, y):

    #set up the figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 9))

    def animate(i):
        # update plot
        pointplot.set_data(x[i], y[i])

        return  pointplot

    # First frame
    ax0 = plt.plot(x,y)
    pointplot, = ax0.plot(x[0], y[0], 'or')

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat = False,
                                   frames=range(1,len(x)), 
                                   interval=200,
                                   blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)

    anim.save('out.mp4')
    plt.close(fig)

# Number of frames
nframes = 200

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 100, num=nframes)
y = np.random.random_sample(np.size(x))

anim_lift(x, y)
```

Now, the file is produced with good quality and pretty small file size, but it takes 15 minutes to produce a 170 frames movie, which is not acceptable for my application. i'm looking for a significant speedup, video file size increase is not a problem.

I believe the bottleneck in the video production is in the temporary saving of the frames in png format. During processing I can see the png files apprearing in my working directory, with the CPU load at 25% only.

Please suggest a solution, that might also be based on a different package rather than simply `matplotlib.animation`, like `OpenCV` (which is anyway already imported in my project) or `moviepy`.

Versions in use:

- python 2.7.3
- matplotlib 1.1.1rc2
- ffmpeg 0.8.17-6:0.8.17-1+rpi1

Answer (score 6):

**Matplotlib 3.4 update:** The solution below can be adapted to work with the latest matplotlib versions. **However**, there seems to have been major performance improvements since this answer was first written and the speed of matplotlib's `FFMpegWriter` is now similar to this solution's writer.

**Original answer**:
The bottleneck of saving an animation to file lies in the use of `figure.savefig()`. Here is a homemade subclass of matplotlib's [`FFMpegWriter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FFMpegFileWriter.html), inspired by gaggio's answer. It doesn't use `savefig` (and thus ignores `savefig_kwargs`) but requires minimal changes to whatever your animation script are.

### For matplotlib < 3.4

```
from matplotlib.animation import FFMpegWriter

class FasterFFMpegWriter(FFMpegWriter):
    '''FFMpeg-pipe writer bypassing figure.savefig.'''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        '''Initialize the Writer object and sets the default frame_format.'''
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.frame_format = 'argb'

    def grab_frame(self, **savefig_kwargs):
        '''Grab the image information from the figure and save as a movie frame.

        Doesn't use savefig to be faster: savefig_kwargs will be ignored.
        '''
        try:
            # re-adjust the figure size and dpi in case it has been changed by the
            # user.  We must ensure that every frame is the same size or
            # the movie will not save correctly.
            self.fig.set_size_inches(self._w, self._h)
            self.fig.set_dpi(self.dpi)
            # Draw and save the frame as an argb string to the pipe sink
            self.fig.canvas.draw()
            self._frame_sink().write(self.fig.canvas.tostring_argb()) 
        except (RuntimeError, IOError) as e:
            out, err = self._proc.communicate()
            raise IOError('Error saving animation to file (cause: {0}) '
                      'Stdout: {1} StdError: {2}. It may help to re-run '
                      'with --verbose-debug.'.format(e, out, err))
```

I was able to create animation in half the time or less than with the default `FFMpegWriter`.

You can use is as explained in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html).

### For matplotlib >= 3.4

The code above will work with matplotlib 3.4 and above if you change the last line of the `try` block to:

```
self._proc.stdin.write(self.fig.canvas.tostring_argb())
```

i.e. using `_proc.stdin` instead of `_frame_sink()`.

Comment: Is this answer still up-to-date? I tried to get it to work with the current matplotlib release, but animation.py apparently has changed since 2018, e.g. _frame_sink() doesn't exist any more. Any suggestions how this could be implemented today?

Comment: I don't have the time or setup to try this right now, but I see in the matplotlib code that the call to `self._frame_sink()` was simply replaced by `self._proc.stdin`. You could try that.
Edit: I'll try to update the answer next week if I have time.

Answer (score 5):

A much improved solution is based on the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092927/generating-movie-from-python-without-saving-individual-frames-to-files) reduces the time by a factor of 10 approximately.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import subprocess

def testSubprocess(x, y):

    #set up the figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 9))
    canvas_width, canvas_height = fig.canvas.get_width_height()

    # First frame
    ax0 = plt.plot(x,y)
    pointplot, = plt.plot(x[0], y[0], 'or')

    def update(frame):
        # your matplotlib code goes here
        pointplot.set_data(x[frame],y[frame])

    # Open an ffmpeg process
    outf = 'testSubprocess.mp4'
    cmdstring = ('ffmpeg', 
                 '-y', '-r', '1', # overwrite, 1fps
                 '-s', '%dx%d' % (canvas_width, canvas_height), # size of image string
                 '-pix_fmt', 'argb', # format
                 '-f', 'rawvideo',  '-i', '-', # tell ffmpeg to expect raw video from the pipe
                 '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', outf) # output encoding
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmdstring, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Draw frames and write to the pipe
    for frame in range(nframes):
        # draw the frame
        update(frame)
        fig.canvas.draw()

        # extract the image as an ARGB string
        string = fig.canvas.tostring_argb()

        # write to pipe
        p.stdin.write(string)

    # Finish up
    p.communicate()

# Number of frames
nframes = 200

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 100, num=nframes)
y = np.random.random_sample(np.size(x))

testSubprocess(x, y)
```

I suspect further speedup might be obtained similarly by piping the raw image data to gstreamer which is now able to benefit from hardware encoding on the Raspberry Pi, see [this discussion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/what-speed-can-i-expect-from-the-hardware-h264-encoding).

Comment: This is very very helpful. The writer class use `fig.savefig()` to save to pipe which is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the writers which will stream right to ffmpeg, but something else is going very wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def anim_lift(x, y):

    #set up the figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 9))

    def animate(i):
        # update plot
        pointplot.set_data(x[i], y[i])

        return [pointplot, ]

    # First frame
    pointplot, = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], 'or')
    ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 200])
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat = False,
                                   frames=range(1,len(x)),
                                   interval=200,
                                   blit=True, repeat_delay=1000)

    anim.save('out.mp4')
    plt.close(fig)


x = list(range(170))
y = list(range(170))
anim_lift(x, y)
```

saving this as test.py (which is a cleaned up version of your code which I don't think actually runs because `plt.plot` returns a list of line2D objects and lists do not have a `plot` method) gives:

```
(dd_py3k) ✔ /tmp 
14:45 $ time python test.py

real    0m7.724s
user    0m9.887s
sys     0m0.547s
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction, actually my version runs thanks to `pointplot[0]` but your version is cleaner, I will edit the original version accordingly.

Comment: Anyway, the problem of speed still remains... Did you notice if your program produces the temporary png files in the working directory? And I assume that your version too is run on raspberry pi 2, raspbian distro? Maybe it is not clear enough in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it took still too long, wherefore I parallelized the proposal from @gaggio with `multiprocessing`. It helped for my machine at least by a magnitude since the proposed solutions with ffmpeg do not seem to have a linear time complexity for the number of frames. Therefore, I assume that chunking the writing process alone, without the parallelization, helps already.

Lets assume you have a matplotlib figure `fig`, an `animate(i)` function which changes the figure for the animation:

```py
import multiprocessing
import math
import os

# divide into chunks (https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/3253411)
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in xrange(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

# number of total frames
frames=1000
frame_iter=[i for i in range(frames)]

# distribute the frames over a set of equally sized chunks
chunk_size=math.ceil(number/multiprocessing.cpu_count())
frame_chunks=list(chunks(frames,chunk_size))

# get temporary video files to write to
filenames=["_temp_video_chunk_" + str(i) + ".mp4") for i in range(len(frame_chunks))]

def ani_to_mp4(frame_set, filename):
    """Animate figure fig for a defined frame set and save in filename (based n (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31315362/3253411)"""
    canvas_width, canvas_height = fig.canvas.get_width_height()

    # Open an ffmpeg process
    outf = os.path.join("results", filename)
    cmdstring = ('ffmpeg', 
                    '-y', '-r', '100', # fps
                    '-s', '%dx%d' % (canvas_width, canvas_height), # size of image string
                    '-pix_fmt', 'argb', # formats
                    '-f', 'rawvideo',  '-i', '-', # tell ffmpeg to expect raw video from the pipe
                    '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', outf) # output encoding
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmdstring, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Draw frames and write to the pipe
    for frame in frame_range:
        # draw the frame
        animate(frame)
        fig.canvas.draw()

        # extract the image as an ARGB string
        string = fig.canvas.tostring_argb()

        # write to pipe
        p.stdin.write(string)

    # Finish up
    p.communicate()

# take the function to write parallelized the animation chunks to the filenames
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.starmap(ani_to_mp4, zip(frame_sets, filenames))

# write the filename list to a file
with open("filenames.txt", "w") as textfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        textfile.write("file '" + filename + "'\n")

# and use ffmpeg to concat the resulting mp4 files
cmdstring = ('ffmpeg', '-y',
                '-f', 'concat', 
                '-safe', '0', 
                '-i', "filenames.txt",
                '-c', 'copy', 
                'output.mp4') # output encoding
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdstring, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I haven't implemented a routine that cleans up the temporary files, but I guess that is not much work.