# Efficiently write a movie directly from np.array using pipes

Tags: python, numpy, video, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have a 4D numpy array of movie frames. I'm looking for a function to write them to a movie, at a given framerate. I have FFMPEG installed on my OS, and [as I can see from these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092927/generating-movie-from-python-without-saving-individual-frames-to-files), the most efficient way to do so is via pipes.

However, I have *very little experience* using pipes, and the explanations in the link above make little sense to me. Furthermore, very few of the answers seem actually implement pipes, and [the one that does](http://vokicodder.blogspot.com/2011/02/numpy-arrays-to-video.html) uses mencoder, not FFMPEG. I am relatively inexperienced with FFMPEG, so am not sure how to modify the command string from the mencoder answer to make it work in FFMPEG.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE:**

A function of the following form:

animate_np_array(4d_array, framerate) -> output.mp4 (or other video codec)

Which implements pipes to send frames one after the other to FFMPEG, and which I can copy-paste into my existing code.

Furthermore, it is absolutely necessary that this function never actually plots any of the frames, as calls to the matplotlib.imshow() function (as I have most typically seen used) slow things down considerably.

Answer (score 18):

The [ImageIO API](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html) offers a dead simple way to do this:

```
import imageio
imageio.mimwrite('output_filename.mp4', np_array , fps = [an int])
```

While I'm not sure if this uses pipes or not, it's blazingly fast.

Comment: Nice. For my situation, the np_array is of the shape 20x512x512, which contains 20 frames of 512x512 pixels of grayscale images.

Comment: This requires both `imageio` and `imageio-ffmpeg` modules. `pip install imageio` `pip install imageio-ffmpeg`