# Add annotation to frames using imageio (python)

Tags: python, arrays, movie, python-imageio

Using the [imageio](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598109/efficiently-write-a-movie-directly-from-np-array-using-pipes), I'd like to add labels to each frame of a resultant movie e.g. Frame 1, Frame 2. I can create the movie but I'm not sure how to add any annotations and can't find anything in the [docs](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Is this possible as we're working on arrays and not images directly?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio

# Create some random data arrays
arrays=[]
for i in range(0,12):
    arrays.append(np.random.rand(500,500))

# Make a movie
imageio.mimwrite('./test_movie.mp4', arrays, fps = 1)
## add an annotation to each frame...
```