# Matplotlib pipe canvas.draw() to ffmpeg - unexpected result

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I'm using this code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525514/6906747) to try and pipe multiple matplotlib plots into ffmpeg to write a video file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess

xlist = np.random.randint(100,size=100)
ylist = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
color = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi = 300)
canvas_width, canvas_height = f.canvas.get_width_height()
ax = f.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('off')


# Open an ffmpeg process
outf = 'ffmpeg.mp4'
cmdstring = ('ffmpeg',
    '-y', '-r', '30', # overwrite, 30fps
    '-s', '%dx%d' % (canvas_width, canvas_height), # size of image string
    '-pix_fmt', 'argb', # format
    '-f', 'rawvideo',  '-i', '-', # tell ffmpeg to expect raw video from the pipe
    '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', outf) # output encoding
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdstring, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Draw 1000 frames and write to the pipe
for frame in range(10):
    print("Working on frame")
    # draw the frame
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
    ax = f.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.scatter(xlist, ylist,
               c=color, cmap = 'viridis')
    f.canvas.draw()
    plt.show()

    # extract the image as an ARGB string
    string = f.canvas.tostring_argb()
    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(string)

# Finish up
p.communicate()
```

While `plt.show()` does show the correct plot (see image below), the video that ffmpeg creates is a bit different than what `plt.show()` shows. I am presuming the issue is with `f.canvas.draw()`, but I'm not sure how to get a look at what `canvas.draw()` actually plots.

plot.show():
[image]

[ffmpeg video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o6IV.jpg) (imgur link)

Comment: Did you make sure to use `'agg'` as the backend?

Comment: @JodyKlymak No, I did not... using `matplotlib.use('agg')`solved the issue. Do you want to post this as an answer? Thanks for your tip!

Comment: Well it was already in the comments of the other answer….