# How to encode a picture into H264 using x264 API?

Tags: c++, x264

I encode a picture following the link [How does one encode a series of images into H264 using the x264 C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940671/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-h264-using-x264-api-c-c), but every time x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out) returns 0.

Comment: A bit vague to be answered; I suggest enabling logs in ffmpeg and checking; BTW, doesn't a return value of 0 indicate success?

Answer (score 1):

What does `x264_encoder_delayed_frames` return? According to [KillianDS's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940671/how-to-encode-series-of-images-into-h264-using-x264-api-c-c/2940700#2940700) at the bottom, `x264_encoder_encode` may return 0 if there are delayed frames.

> When you use other parameters there will be delayed frames, this is not the case with my parameters (mostly due to the nolatency option). If this is the case, frame_size will sometimes be zero and you'll have to call x264_encoder_encode as long as the function x264_encoder_delayed_frames does not return 0. But for this functionality you should take a deeper peek into x264.c and x264.h .