# Taking a video of the application in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-screen

I understand that to take video of the application you need to have  your phone rooted in android. What feature puts this restriction?
**Workaround**
I want  to know how feasible this is? Take screenshots of the UI on regular intervals(very quick intervals) and convert those pictures into a video. 

**NOTE**
By screenshot I mean the area of only my application's layout. I want to take rapid screenshots of the layout and then convert it into a video. If it is possible, when saving the current state of the layout in a bitmap, will it do so in a UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to capture the current application activity you can use this code in a thread with a timer.

```
RelativeLayout rl1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_1);
        View v1 = rl1.getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and you can make a video. refer  [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969423/jcodec-has-anyone-seen-documentation-on-this-library)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430418/capture-screen-shot-on-android-using-java-code) solution if you want to capture your own application activities.

Capturing the phone's entire screen is only possible using the the [READ_FRAME_BUFFER permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_FRAME_BUFFER) which allows system (non 3rd party!) apps to take screenshots. This is why this solution works for rooted devices only. You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837910/2366413).

Comment: Thanks for the reason. I want to capture my application activities. I wasnt to know how feasible it is to take rapid screenshots of my activity and then make a video out of the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to capture some fluid images of your app in action, you might just try video capturing/taking screenshots of your app on your desktop while running the app in the Android emulator.