# How to create a mp4 video from images in Java by using JCodec library?

Tags: java

I am doing the research about how to create a mp4 video from images in Java. After a few days researching, I know that JCodec can do it (http://jcodec.org/). Here is the demonstration I found on [Android make animated video from list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images) (I only changed the input and output link):

```
private SeekableByteChannel ch;
private Picture toEncode;
private RgbToYuv420 transform;
private H264Encoder encoder;
private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
private CompressedTrack outTrack;
private ByteBuffer _out;
private int frameNo;
private MP4Muxer muxer;

public SequenceImagesEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
    this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

    // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
    transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

    // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
    muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

    // Add video track to muxer
    outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

    // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
    _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

    // Create an instance of encoder
    encoder = new H264Encoder();

    // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
    // MP4
    spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
    ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

}

public void encodeImage(BufferedImage bi) throws IOException {
    if (toEncode == null) {
        toEncode = Picture.create(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), ColorSpace.YUV420);
    }

    // Perform conversion
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Arrays.fill(toEncode.getData()[i], 0);
    transform.transform(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi), toEncode);

    // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
    _out.clear();
    ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

    // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
    spsList.clear();
    ppsList.clear();
    H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

    // Add packet to video track
    outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 25, 1, frameNo, true, null, frameNo, 0));

    frameNo++;
}

public void finish() throws IOException {
    // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
    outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

    // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
    muxer.writeHeader();
    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SequenceImagesEncoder encoder = new SequenceImagesEncoder(new File("D:/workspace/JCodecMakeMP4/out.mp4"));
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(String.format("D:/workspace/JCodecMakeMP4/bin/frame" + i + ".jpeg", i)));
        encoder.encodeImage(bi);
    }
    encoder.finish();
}
```

When I use jcodec-0.1.0.jar, the class NIOUtils does not have a function: writableFileChannel(File file).

When I use jcodec-0.1.3.jar, everything seem to be ok, but I debug the code, it lead to "Source Not Found" when i move to line: muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

Does anyone know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [jcodec - has anyone seen documentation on this library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969423/jcodec-has-anyone-seen-documentation-on-this-library) might help (see the code in the answer)

Comment: I also found that code on this webside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images

When I try to use jcodec-0.1.0.jar, the functions: 
NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out); does not appear. 
I use jcodec-0.1.3.jar everything seem to be ok but when I run the code, it cause an error: "Source not found" when reach the line of code:
muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

Comment: If you need more help then your next step is probably to provide your code [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just edited my post. Hope it can help you DavidPostill

Answer (score 9):

It is just share my experience. I use `JpegImagesToMovie` to solve like your problem.

For more reference [JpegImagesToMovie](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jpegimagestomovie-176885.html).

Sample Program

```
public static void makeVideo(String fileName) throws MalformedURLException {
    Vector<String> imgLst = get images path list.

    JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
    MediaLocator oml;
    if ((oml = imageToMovie.createMediaLocator(fileName)) == null) {
        System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    int interval = 50;
    imageToMovie.doIt(screenWidth, screenHeight, (1000 / interval), imgLst, oml);

}
```

JpegImagesToMovie.java

```
/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
import javax.media.Time;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;
import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferDataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferStream;

/**
 * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
 * QuickTime movie.
 */
public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

    public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles,
            MediaLocator outML) throws MalformedURLException {
        ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
                inFiles);

        Processor p;

        try {
            //System.err
            //      .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
            p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
            return false;
        }

        p.addControllerListener(this);

        // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
        // some processing options on the processor.
        p.configure();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
        p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        // Query for the processor for supported formats.
        // Then set it on the processor.
        TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
        if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
            System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                    + tcs[0].getFormat());
            return false;
        }

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        //System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

        // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
        // realize it.
        p.realize();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
        DataSink dsink;
        if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                            + outML);
            return false;
        }

        dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        fileDone = false;

        System.out.println("Generating the video : "+outML.getURL().toString());

        // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
        try {
            p.start();
            dsink.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO error during processing");
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for EndOfStream event.
        waitForFileDone();

        // Cleanup.
        try {
            dsink.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        p.removeControllerListener(this);

        System.out.println("Video creation completed!!!!!");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Create the DataSink.
     */
    DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

        DataSource ds;

        if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
            return null;
        }

        DataSink dsink;

        try {
            //System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
            dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
            dsink.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
            return null;
        }

        return dsink;
    }

    Object waitSync = new Object();
    boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

    /**
     * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
     * false if the transition failed.
     */
    boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            try {
                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                    waitSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return stateTransitionOK;
    }

    /**
     * Controller Listener.
     */
    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = true;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = false;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
            evt.getSourceController().stop();
            evt.getSourceController().close();
        }
    }

    Object waitFileSync = new Object();
    boolean fileDone = false;
    boolean fileSuccess = true;

    /**
     * Block until file writing is done.
     */
    boolean waitForFileDone() {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            try {
                while (!fileDone)
                    waitFileSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return fileSuccess;
    }

    /**
     * Event handler for the file writer.
     */
    public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                fileSuccess = false;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    /*public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (args.length == 0)
            prUsage();

        // Parse the arguments.
        int i = 0;
        int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = 1;
        Vector inputFiles = new Vector();
        String outputURL = null;

        while (i < args.length) {

            if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                frameRate = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                outputURL = args[i];
            } else {
                inputFiles.addElement(args[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (outputURL == null || inputFiles.size() == 0)
            prUsage();

        // Check for output file extension.
        if (!outputURL.endsWith(".mov") && !outputURL.endsWith(".MOV")) {
            System.err
                    .println("The output file extension should end with a .mov extension");
            prUsage();
        }

        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            System.err.println("Please specify the correct image size.");
            prUsage();
        }

        // Check the frame rate.
        if (frameRate < 1)
            frameRate = 1;

        // Generate the output media locators.
        MediaLocator oml;

        if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
            System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
        imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

        System.exit(0);
    }*/

    static void prUsage() {
        System.err
                .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    /**
     * Create a media locator from the given string.
     */
    static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

        MediaLocator ml;

        if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
            return ml;

        if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                return ml;
        } else {
            String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + File.separator + url;
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                return ml;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Inner classes.
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
     * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
     */
    class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

        ImageSourceStream streams[];

        ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
            streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
            streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
        }

        public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
        }

        public MediaLocator getLocator() {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
         * without a container format.
         */
        public String getContentType() {
            return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
        }

        public void connect() {
        }

        public void disconnect() {
        }

        public void start() {
        }

        public void stop() {
        }

        /**
         * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
         */
        public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
            return streams;
        }

        /**
         * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
         * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
         */
        public Time getDuration() {
            return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
     */
    class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

        Vector images;
        int width, height;
        VideoFormat format;

        int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
        boolean ended = false;

        public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                Vector images) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.images = images;

            format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                    height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                    (float) frameRate);
        }

        /**
         * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
         */
        public boolean willReadBlock() {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
         * data.
         */
        public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

            // Check if we've finished all the frames.
            if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                buf.setEOM(true);
                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength(0);
                ended = true;
                return;
            }

            String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
            nextImage++;

            //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

            // Open a random access file for the next image.
            RandomAccessFile raFile;
            raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

            byte data[] = null;

            // Check the input buffer type & size.

            if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

            // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
            if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                buf.setData(data);
            }

            // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
            raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

            //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

            buf.setOffset(0);
            buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
            buf.setFormat(format);
            buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

            // Close the random access file.
            raFile.close();
        }

        /**
         * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
         */
        public Format getFormat() {
            return format;
        }

        public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
            return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
        }

        public long getContentLength() {
            return 0;
        }

        public boolean endOfStream() {
            return ended;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if we can create a mp4 video from images via your sample code? Because I am working with mp4 format.

Comment: @user3675966 It is ok for `mp4` format. Just use file name like 'xxx.mp4'.

Comment: I try to apply your sample but it got some error. Here is my step:
Exception in thread "JMF thread: SendEventQueue: com.sun.media.processor.unknown.Handler" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.media.multiplexer.video.QuicktimeMux.writeVideoSampleDescription(QuicktimeMux.java:936) ... and so on

Comment: did u add `jmf-2.1.1e.jar` in your class path?

Comment: i only add jmf.jar. Should I add jmf-2.1.1e.jar too?

Comment: I replaced the jmf.jar by jmf-2.1.1e.jar. I create a video from 10 pictures with interval = 50 and frameRate = 1000/ interval. It works only one time. Did you get any solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi, I have a problem to generate a video in mp4 format. If I add the .mp4 extension, it is completed by .mov `filename.mp4.mov`

Comment: It creates an `.mov` extension file which also not played in *windows media player*. Its a quick time playable.

Comment: @CycDemo Change to mp4 works fine to me, but video cannot be played on Windows Media Player. I think `p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));` should be change to `MSVIDEO`, but it still not working. Any idea?

Comment: @NPE , to play video on player. it is depend on payer media code pack. You might need to install a required media code-pack on player.

Comment: @CycDemo On the code above, what code pack we need?

Comment: @NPE  another options. change the file extension to `wmv`. I am not sure for that but I hope so

Comment: Im getting the same exception Exception in thread "JMF thread: SendEventQueue: com.sun.media.processor.unknown.Handler" java.lang.NullPointerException. I have added jmf as gradle dependency. Could anyone please give me a solution for this?@LuongTruong @Zaw Than oo