# Convert OpenGL output to H264 with x264

Tags: c++, c, h.264, x264, libx264

I want to convert the output of an OpenGL Program to h264 and stream the output. I got collected most of the code somewhere and I get an output file but I have no Idea what to do with it, or if it is valid. Currently the output is just saved in file.h264.

Edit: "Global" Variables

```
    x264_param_t param;
    x264_t* encoder;
    x264_picture_t pic_in;
    x264_picture_t pic_out;

    x264_nal_t *headers;
    int i_nal;
    FILE* pFile;
```

My init function:

```
initX264() {
    pFile = fopen("file.h264", "wb");

    x264_param_t param;
    x264_param_default_preset(&param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
    param.i_threads = 1;
    param.i_width = 1024;
    param.i_height = 768;
    param.i_fps_num = 30;
    param.i_fps_den = 1;

    param.i_keyint_max = 30;
    param.b_intra_refresh = 1;

    param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;

    param.b_annexb = 0;
    param.b_repeat_headers = 0;

    param.i_log_level = X264_LOG_DEBUG;

    x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "baseline");

    encoder = x264_encoder_open(&param);
    x264_picture_alloc(&pic_in, X264_CSP_I420, 1024, 768);

    x264_encoder_parameters( encoder, &param );

    x264_encoder_headers( encoder, &headers, &i_nal );

    int size = headers[0].i_payload + headers[1].i_payload + headers[2].i_payload;
    fwrite( headers[0].p_payload, 1, size, pFile);
}
```

This goes in the Render function and is executed about 30 times per second:

```
    GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[3 * 1024 * 768];
    GLubyte *PixelYUV = new GLubyte[3 * 1024 * 768];

    glReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 768, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    RGB2YUV(1024, 768, data, PixelYUV, PixelYUV + 1024 * 768, PixelYUV + 1024 * 768 + (1024 * 768) / 4, true);
    pic_in.img.plane[0] = PixelYUV;
    pic_in.img.plane[1] = PixelYUV + 1024 * 768;
    pic_in.img.plane[2] = PixelYUV + 1024 * 768 + (1024 * 768) / 4;

    x264_nal_t* nals;
    int i_nals;
    int frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);

    if( frame_size )
    {
        fwrite( (char*)nals[0].p_payload, frame_size, 1, pFile );

    }
```

I got the GRB2YUV funktion from http://svn.gnumonks.org/trunk/21c3-video/cutting_tagging/tools/mpeg4ip-1.2/server/util/rgb2yuv/rgb2yuv.c

The output looks like

```
x264 [debug]: frame=   0 QP=11.14 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3072 P:0    SKIP:0    size=21133 bytes
x264 [debug]: frame=   1 QP=20.08 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:0    P:14   SKIP:3058 size=72 bytes
x264 [debug]: frame=   2 QP=18.66 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:0    P:48   SKIP:3024 size=161 bytes
x264 [debug]: frame=   3 QP=18.23 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:6   I:0    P:84   SKIP:2988 size=293 bytes
```

On Linux file file.h264 returns data.

Comment: does it play in vlc media player? If it does, then you're encoding it correctly.  If not, then you're not encoding the video correctly.

Comment: no vlc or avplay cannot play it.

Comment: Where do you declare pic_in?

Comment: Edit: Added Global Variable declarations

Comment: THe x264 settings will be different depending on the container (or protocol) you wish to write to. Is the stream destined to a streaming service such as twitch.tv?

Comment: I want to stream like rtsp, so anyone who accesses rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/stream to be able to view the stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file format is bad. Nothing will be able to read that. A .264 uses annexB with headers prepended to IDR frames.

change these parameters,

```
param.b_annexb = 1;
param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
```

And delete

```
x264_encoder_headers( encoder, &headers, &i_nal );
int size = headers[0].i_payload + headers[1].i_payload + headers[2].i_payload;
fwrite( headers[0].p_payload, 1, size, pFile);
```

Finally you should be able to take your output and convert it to an mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i file.264 -vcodec copy -an file.mp4
```

Comment: FYI. This if for .264 files. If you are streaming to RTMP, you will need to create a sequence header from x264_encoder_headers(), and switch back to b_annexb = 0;

Comment: For files this works great. How can I stream to RTMP, what Library (for Linux and Windows) should I use?

Comment: https://github.com/szatmary/RtmpBroadcaster.
Look at rtmp.cpp, flvtag.cpp and encode.cpp.
Are you streaming a video game?

Comment: thanks I will have a look at that. It is not a Video game, just a simulation program that uses OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 X264 expects YUV420P data (I guess some others also, but that's the common one). You can use libswscale (from ffmpeg) to convert images to the right format. Initializing this is like this (i assume RGB data with 24bpp).
```

That's most likely why you're not getting any usable video.  You can find more about what to do here: [How does one encode a series of images into H264 using the x264 C API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940671/how-does-one-encode-a-series-of-images-into-h264-using-the-x264-c-api)

To scale:

```
 sws_scale(convertCtx, &data, &srcstride, 0, h, pic_in.img.plane, pic_in.img.stride);
 //pic_in is your RGB data getting fed to scale.
```

Comment: I wanted to get around using libffmpeg just for YUV420P conversion. So you think the RGB2YUV function is broken?

Comment: Not broken, but maybe different than what you think its doing.  Which library are you getting that from?  Are you sure its taking RGB and going to YUV420P?  It could be doing YUV444 to RGB888, which might not work.

Comment: "I got the GRB2YUV funktion from http://svn.gnumonks.org/trunk/21c3-video/cutting_tagging/tools/mpeg4ip-1.2/server/util/rgb2yuv/rgb2yuv.c "

Comment: I think you have to scale it in order to get it to work.  There seems to be some specifications about how the image should be scaled before encoding the image.  Use the way in my link and I bet you it will work.

Comment: so how do I feed the RGB Data to sws_scale?

Comment: where does srcstride come from? data is the pointer to the beginning of the RGB data, h is 768 (im my case), pic_in is the output of sws_scale? pic_in.img.stride is undefined did you mean pic_in.img.i_stride?

Comment: They might have changed the parameter name, so yes, whichever property represents the stride(which gets auto computed).