# Small C program compiles, but tries to import functions from wrong DLLs

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, dependency-walker

I have a small C program that uses 3 DLLs.  It uses 8 functions from the first DLL.  5 functions from the second DLL.  And 2 functions from the 3rd DLL.

Problem 1)  When I open the outputed executable with Dependency Walker, the executable only tries to import 2 functions from each DLL.  That can't be right.

Problem 2)  What's worse, it tries to import the *same* 2 functions from each DLL.  But only one of the DLLs has these 2 functions it's even trying to import.  So the executable throws an error saying it can't find a function.  But of course it can't, because it's looking inside DLLs that clearly don't have the function.

Question)  How do I fix this?  I want to open the executable with Dependency Walker and see that it tries to import 8 functions from the first DLL.  5 functions from the second DLL.  And 2 functions from the 3rd DLL.  And I want to see that it tries to import the right functions from the right DLLs.

*Hopefully someone can help me based on just the information above.  But if not, hopefully I can edit this question, and I will include all the details including the source code of the program (it's one file and short).  Screenshots of Dependency Walker.  Links to the .h, .lib, and .dll files (they are a part of libx264).  And screenshots of all the settings in Visual Studio that are needed to get the program to build without any errors.*

**Aditional Information...**

Sorry I'm new to C programming but I will try to provide enough information.

The following is a C program that uses libx264 (or maybe an ffmpeg API that uses libx264 behind the scenes) that manually draws raw RGB images (as uint8_t arrays), feeds them to the libx264 encoder, receives individual x264 frames from the encoder, and writes the x264 frames to a file (as uint8_t arrays).  These x264 frames can then be fed to a decoder.  But this program just encodes.

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

static AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPacket pkt;
static FILE *file;
struct SwsContext *sws_context = NULL; 

static void ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(uint8_t *rgb) {
    const int in_linesize[1] = { 3 * c->width };
    sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context,
        c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        c->width, c->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
        0, 0, 0, 0);
    sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *)&rgb, in_linesize, 0,
        c->height, frame->data, frame->linesize);
}

uint8_t* generate_rgb(int width, int height, int pts, uint8_t *rgb) {
    int x, y, cur;
    rgb = (uint8_t*)realloc(rgb, 3 * sizeof(uint8_t) * height * width);
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            cur = 3 * (y * width + x);
            rgb[cur + 0] = 0;
            rgb[cur + 1] = 0;
            rgb[cur + 2] = 0;
            if ((frame->pts / 25) % 2 == 0) {
                if (y < height / 2) {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        /* Black. */
                    }
                    else {
                        rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                    }
                    else {
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if (y < height / 2) {
                    rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                    }
                    else {
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (x < width / 2) {
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                    else {
                        rgb[cur + 0] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 1] = 255;
                        rgb[cur + 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rgb;
}

/* Allocate resources and write header data to the output file. */
void ffmpeg_encoder_start(const char *filename, int codec_id, int fps, int width, int height) {
    AVCodec *codec;
    int ret;

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->width = width;
    c->height = height;
    c->time_base.num = 1;
    c->time_base.den = fps;
    c->keyint_min = 600;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/*
Write trailing data to the output file
and free resources allocated by ffmpeg_encoder_start.
*/
void ffmpeg_encoder_finish(void) {
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
    int got_output, ret;
    do {
        fflush(stdout);
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (got_output) {
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
    } while (got_output);
    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), file);
    fclose(file);
    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
}

/*
Encode one frame from an RGB24 input and save it to the output file.
Must be called after ffmpeg_encoder_start, and ffmpeg_encoder_finish
must be called after the last call to this function.
*/
void ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(uint8_t *rgb) {
    int ret, got_output;
    ffmpeg_encoder_set_frame_yuv_from_rgb(rgb);
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;
    if (frame->pts == 1) {
        frame->key_frame = 1;
        frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
    }
    else {
        frame->key_frame = 0;
        frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P;
    }
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (got_output) {
        fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
}

/* Represents the main loop of an application which generates one frame per loop. */
static void encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id) {
    int pts;
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;
    uint8_t *rgb = NULL;
    ffmpeg_encoder_start(filename, codec_id, 25, width, height);
    for (pts = 0; pts < 100; pts++) {
        frame->pts = pts;
        rgb = generate_rgb(width, height, pts, rgb);
        ffmpeg_encoder_encode_frame(rgb);
    }
    ffmpeg_encoder_finish();
}

int main(void) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    encode_example("tmp.h264", AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    encode_example("tmp.mpg", AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    return 0;
}
```

The line `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` ignores depreciation warnings that are treated as errors.  You can see that some of the functions I'm using are marked as depreciated in the header files.  I'll worry about that later, right now I just need something that runs.

The .h, .lib, and .dll files can be found here: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

There are some download options on that site: [Screenshot of Download Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj2Pg.png)

I'm using that 64-bit beta version of the .h, .lib, and .dll files.  You also have to select if you want to download the "Static", "Shared", or "Dev" version of the files.  The "Shared" version has the .dll files.  The "Dev" version has the .h and .lib files.  So I needed both of those.

I was advised to not post screenshots of settings in Visual Studio but I'll summary of what I did in Visual Studio to get the program to build.  I had to make sure the project was set to 64-bit output (it was 32-bit by default).  I had to tell Visual Studio to compile and link C not C++ code (maybe I did this by renaming the source code file extension to .c instead of .cpp, I can't remember).  I put the folders with the .lib files and .h files in a logical place inside my project folder and added the folder paths to the places Visual Studio will look for .lib files and .h files.  I also had to specifically name the .lib files I was using.  After building I put the .dll files in the same folder as the compiled executable.  There might have been something else but I can't remember.

I was also advised not to make screenshots of Dependency Walker, and instead paste output from the command:

> dumpbin /imports LibLinkingTest.exe

LibLinkingTest.exe is the name of the executable that was compiled from the C source code above, based on the name I gave to my project.  Here is the output from that command above:

> Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.12.25835.0 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Dump of file LibLinkingTest.exe
>
> File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
>
> Section contains the following imports:
>
> ```
> avcodec-58.dll
>          1400221D8 Import Address Table
>          1400226D8 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                        C sws_getCachedContext
>                       1B sws_scale
>
> avutil-56.dll
>          1400221D8 Import Address Table
>          1400226D8 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                        C sws_getCachedContext
>                       1B sws_scale
>
> swscale-5.dll
>          1400221D8 Import Address Table
>          1400226D8 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                        C sws_getCachedContext
>                       1B sws_scale
>
> VCRUNTIME140D.dll
>          140022150 Import Address Table
>          140022650 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                       31 __vcrt_LoadLibraryExW
>                       2F __vcrt_GetModuleHandleW
>                       25 __std_type_info_destroy_list
>                        8 __C_specific_handler
>                       2E __vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW
>
> ucrtbased.dll
>          140022270 Import Address Table
>          140022770 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                       4D __p__commode
>                      52B strcpy_s
>                      527 strcat_s
>                       68 __stdio_common_vsprintf_s
>                      2C1 _seh_filter_dll
>                      172 _initialize_onexit_table
>                      2B4 _register_onexit_function
>                       E5 _execute_onexit_table
>                       C2 _crt_atexit
>                       C1 _crt_at_quick_exit
>                      54A terminate
>                      39B _wmakepath_s
>                      3B7 _wsplitpath_s
>                      563 wcscpy_s
>                       B5 _configthreadlocale
>                      2CA _set_fmode
>                      2B5 _register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback
>                      175 _initterm_e
>                      174 _initterm
>                      13D _get_initial_narrow_environment
>                      171 _initialize_narrow_environment
>                       B6 _configure_narrow_argv
>                       5B __setusermatherr
>                      2C5 _set_app_type
>                      2C2 _seh_filter_exe
>                        5 _CrtDbgReportW
>                        4 _CrtDbgReport
>                      44F exit
>                      504 realloc
>                       5C __stdio_common_vfprintf
>                      48A fwrite
>                      47B fopen
>                      468 fflush
>                      459 fclose
>                       35 __acrt_iob_func
>                      2CD _set_new_mode
>                       A4 _cexit
>                       9F _c_exit
>                       EA _exit
>                       4A __p___argv
>                       49 __p___argc
>
> KERNEL32.dll
>          140022000 Import Address Table
>          140022500 Import Name Table
>                  0 time date stamp
>                  0 Index of first forwarder reference
>
>                      37D IsDebuggerPresent
>                      45F RaiseException
>                      3EB MultiByteToWideChar
>                      605 WideCharToMultiByte
>                      4CB RtlCaptureContext
>                      4D2 RtlLookupFunctionEntry
>                      4D9 RtlVirtualUnwind
>                      5B4 UnhandledExceptionFilter
>                      573 SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
>                      2B1 GetProcAddress
>                      1AF FreeLibrary
>                      5D5 VirtualQuery
>                      21B GetCurrentProcess
>                      592 TerminateProcess
>                      2B7 GetProcessHeap
>                      34E HeapFree
>                      384 IsProcessorFeaturePresent
>                      34A HeapAlloc
>                      449 QueryPerformanceCounter
>                      21C GetCurrentProcessId
>                      220 GetCurrentThreadId
>                      2EC GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
>                      367 InitializeSListHead
>                      2D3 GetStartupInfoW
>                      27A GetModuleHandleW
>                      263 GetLastError
> ```
>
> Summary
>
> ```
>     1000 .00cfg
>     1000 .data
>     2000 .idata
>     3000 .pdata
>     3000 .rdata
>     1000 .reloc
>     1000 .rsrc
>     A000 .text
>    10000 .textbss
> ```

It's associating the functions `sws_getCachedContext` and `sws_scale` which are used in the C source code above with 3 DLLs:  avcodec-58.dll, avutil-56.dll, and swscale-5.dll

But the functions `sws_getCachedContext` and `sws_scale` are only present in swscale-5.dll.

And there is no mention of the 13 other functions in the C source code above that should be loaded from these DLLs.

The functions `avcodec_find_encoder`, `avcodec_alloc_context3`, `avcodec_encode_video2`, `avcodec_open2`, `avcodec_close`, `avcodec_register_all`, `av_packet_unref`, and `av_init_packet` from the C source code above should be loaded from avcodec-58.dll.

The functions `av_opt_set`, `av_image_alloc`, `av_free`, `av_freep`, and `av_frame_free` from the C source code above should be loaded from avutil-56.dll.

The functions `sws_getCachedContext` and `sws_scale` from the C source code above should be loaded from swscale-5.dll (so it looks like it actually got that right).

These function are definitely present in these DLLs because I can see them inside the DLLs using Dependency Walker.  I'm pretty sure that none of these functions are statically embedded inside the final executable.  All of these functions should be loaded from the DLLs.

And I was advised to post the build log.  Here is the build log:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.12.25835 for x64
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl /c /ZI /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /sdl /Od /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE
>   /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise
>   /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"x64\Debug\"
>   /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:prompt LibLinkingTest.c
>
> LibLinkingTest.c
>   Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.12.25835.0
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> "/OUT:C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Windows\VS2017\LibLinkingTest\x64\Debug\LibLinkingTest.exe"
>   /INCREMENTAL avcodec.lib avdevice.lib avfilter.lib avformat.lib
>   avutil.lib postproc.lib swresample.lib swscale.lib kernel32.lib
>   user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
>   shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
>   /MANIFEST "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /manifest:embed /DEBUG:FASTLINK
>   "/PDB:C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Windows\VS2017\LibLinkingTest\x64\Debug\LibLinkingTest.pdb"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT
>   "/IMPLIB:C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Windows\VS2017\LibLinkingTest\x64\Debug\LibLinkingTest.lib"
>   /MACHINE:X64 x64\Debug\LibLinkingTest.obj  x64\Debug\stdafx.obj
>   LibLinkingTest.vcxproj ->
>   C:\Users\me\Desktop\Programming\Windows\VS2017\LibLinkingTest\x64\Debug\LibLinkingTest.exe

Comment: The only way for what you describe to happen is for the Import Library(s) not to match the DLLs.

Comment: "*Question) How do I fix this?*", is the problem really just dependency walker's behavior? Is that behavior correct? Also, could you post an example of 1. How your program "*imports*" those functions? 2. How do you compile and link your program?

Comment: Instead of screenshots of dependency walker, use `dumpbin /imports` to get the information neatly in text form.  Instead of screenshots of Visual Studio project properties, paste the build log where the compiler and linker command lines are shown.   Information included as quoted text in the question is generally significantly more useful than pictures, unless you're talking about a graphics bug.

Comment: Did you use the same "module handle" for the same dlls?

Comment: @Raindrop7: Module handles are involved in the runtime loading process, but don't apply to imports.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know the import time is right before compilation. But don't you think that the OP has a runtime problem instead of import-time one?

Comment: @Raindrop7: It could be a runtime, problem, if he's using Dependency Walker "profiling" mode to observe `GetProcAddress` calls.  But from the question it seems that he's looking at the static import table.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ok get it. Thanx.

Comment: Did you copy all DLLs to the same folder which contains the executable?

Comment: @MahmoudFayez Yes, all DLLs are in the same folder as the executable.  If I remove one of them I get a different error about a missing DLL.

Comment: Are you using the `.def` files that are included in the "dev" download? Module definition files are usually required for correct exports in Windows builds. The property pages of your VS project will have a place to include one or more module definition files.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I don't think I'm using the .def files because I don't know what those are.  But I will try to use them.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )   The posted code causes the compiler to output about a dozen warning, some of which are critical.

Comment: defining a function inside another function is not allowed (although the `gcc`, with extensions, will allow it.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: the function: `ate_rgb()` is missing a return type

Comment: since there is only a single file, there is no need to add the `static` modifier to the functions and global variables

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Visual Studio will only let me set one .def file for the project.  But there are several of them included with the .lib files.  What can I do?

Comment: this statement: `uint8_t* generstatic void encode_example(
        const char *filename,
        int codec_id)` is missing a trailing '{'

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);`  This fails to tell the user WHY the call to `fopen()` failed.  Either include a call to the function: `strerror()` or (better) call `perror()`

Comment: on linux 16.04, this type: `SwsContext` is not defined within the included header files.

Comment: @user3629249 I don't understand your comments.  The C source code I provided was copied and pasted verbatim from another stackoverflow post with the exception of `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` because at the time of that post none of these functions were declared depreciated.  No one commented on their code.  And there is no function `ate_rgb()`, there are no functions declared inside functions, there is no statement `uint8_t* generstatic void encode_example( const char *filename, int codec_id)`.  I don't care why `fopen()` failed.  This is not a finished product it is a test.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, you're building an .exe, not a .dll. The .def files aren't needed for that. This could go back and forth for quite a long time -- this sort of build scenario in VS is not one for a novice.

Comment: I copy/paste the posted code, and passed it to my compiler.  It does not compile.  Regardless of what some other stackoverflow post may or may not have shown.  Suggest posting a link to that other stackoverflow question.

Comment: @user3629249 You tell me.  It doesn't exist in the C source code I posted.  Look at the C source code on this webpage, not what you think you copied and pasted correctly.  But what is actually on this page.

Comment: @user3629249 With the exception of `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` this code is a verbatim copy from this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940671/how-does-one-encode-a-series-of-images-into-h264-using-the-x264-c-api

Comment: It would be interesting to see the results of `dumpbin /symbols` on the .obj file made by the compiler.  We could see if the functions you're expecting to use from a DLL are indeed undefined (the linker will fill them in using the import library) or if somehow the compiler got rid of them (perhaps they are defined in the header files, either as inline functions or macros)

Comment: Your problem is that the .lib files don't match the .dll's. I downloaded the stable versions of "dev" and "shared", and the `avcodec.lib` file was calling out "avcodec-58.dll", but the .dll in the package was "avcodec-57.dll". You need to talk to the folks at ffmpeg and yank their chain.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone.  The page where I downloaded the .h, .lib, and .dll files also had older versions available.  I downloaded version 3.2 of the Dev and Shared files and everything works.  The people at ffmpeg that prepare the files have made a mistake on the latest version.

Comment: only the last answer (starting with: FFmpeg 2.8.6 runnable example) has a complete application, so I guess that is the code your referring to).  That code does not cleanly compile.  Amongst (many) other problems, it is missing the header file: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the `realloc()` function

Comment: regarding: `rgb = realloc(rgb, 3 * sizeof(uint8_t) * height * width);`  Here it is multiplying a 'size_t` (which is unsigned long) by two `int` types (height and width)

Comment: regarding: `uint8_t* generate_rgb(int width, int height, int pts, uint8_t *rgb)`  this function has the unused parameter: `int ptr`,

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, file);`  the third parameter, `pkt.size`, the function is expecting a 'size_t' (which is unsigned) but the passed variable is a `int` (which is signed)

Comment: in general, if your code is calling some system function,do not depend on some header file over which you do not have control to actually include some header file for functions you directly call.  so the posted code should have: `#include <stdio.h>` (for `fprintf(), etc) and `#include <ctype.h>` (for `uint8_t`, etc) and `#include <stdlib.h>` (for  `exit()`, etc)